internal monitor freezes
I run Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I use an external monitor and my laptop's monitor in parallel. The external monitor is the primary monitor. From time to time the internal monitor freezes. Ubuntu still operate the monitor in the sense that if I click on some button for example in the freezed monitor (without that I see it) it operates as expected. A temporary solution is to physically close the laptop's monitor and then reopen it, and it is settled. But can I solve it permanently? In other questions I saw a similar problem arises when using GPU, but I don't use GPU.

Please edit your question and add information which hardware you are using, especially which graphic unit drives your laptop.
